# Salesforce re-authenticate the token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce

Salesforce sessions automatically timeout after 2 hours so that we'll need to refresh the tokens, anyone can suggest the user has to re-authorize the app every two hours via [databasedotcom](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not sample Ruby code, but describes how to refresh a token:

The client application obtains a new access token by POSTing another request (4) to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token, this time with payload of the form:

> grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNINVBJGKrUKSXjJRTgKoeZx6OvJLXwLO8n80_OY.ydx0cQ24zGwBhRfa4YEWrFaNVVdI142EivZ&client_secret=7868057769520845245&refresh_token=5Aep861eWO5D.7wJBuW5aaARbbxQ8hssCnY1dw3qi59o1du7ob.lp23ba_3jMRnbFNT5R8X2GUKNA==

```
grant_type  Set this to refresh_token.
client_id   Your application's client identifier.
client_secret   Your application's client secret (optional).
refresh_token   The refresh token provided in the previous authorization.
```

On receipt of the access token, the client can repeat its request (5), send a response to the user (6), and carry on servicing requests (7, 8, 9) until the new access token expires.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Token_Refresh

Comment: Thanks but how to re-authorize using old token to get new token without user login again

Comment: You can configure refresh token policy here:   Setup, click Manage Apps | Connected Apps | Refresh Token Policy

Comment: Thanks again. in ruby using `databasedomcom gem` how to do re-authorize like sample ruby code

Comment: I just called `client.authenticate` it will fetch new token